# how to ignore a value in a text?

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I have a string like this :

```
EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=50,EPRE=ENABLED
```

how can I ignore, the value of QLPUB? Actually I want to check this string in 3000 lines but I want to ignore 50.

is there any way to ignore it, for example with java regular expression or %s or ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If value of QLPUB is always numeric you can use the following regex:

```
^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=\d*,EPRE=ENABLED$
```

Here's an example:

```
String text = "EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=502,EPRE=ENABLED";      
String pattern = "^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=\\d*,EPRE=ENABLED$";

Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(text);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If the value of QLPUB is anything but a `,` change the regex to:

```
^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=[^,]*,EPRE=ENABLED$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(^|,)QLPUB=[^,]*", "");
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/7CZMO)

Comment: thanks , but i want to see this in output : EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=x,EPRE=ENABLED, in this case x can be anything !

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex `/^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=\d+,EPRE=ENABLED$/`.  In java this would look like this:

```
String myString = "EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=50,EPRE=ENABLED";
if(myString.matches("^EQ=ENABLED,QLPUB=\\d+,EPRE=ENABLED$"))
{
    //your string matches regardless of the value of QLPUB
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to escape `,` and since OP is going to test several lines it would be better to use a precompiled pattern :)

Comment: I realised about escaping `.` (bad habit from my old perl days where our weird implementation required escaping pretty much everything).  As for compiling, yes, agree, I just wanted to show the simplest possible way.